# Abstract class observable not triggering, Angular 11 ts 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Take this class

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class Class1 {
    public abstract $obs: Observable<any>;
}
```

And this class that implements it

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class Class1Service implements Class1 {
private obs: ReplaySubject<any> = new Replaysubject();
public $obs: Observable<any> = this.obs.asObservable();
}
```

In the module the `Class1` is set up in `providers` like so:

```
.
.
.
providers: [
{
provide: Class1,
useClass: Class1Service
}]
```

If i inject `Class1Service` and go `$obs.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));` works fine.
When i inject `Class1`  and go `$obs.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));` it doesnt trigger.

Can anyone explain to me why that is?

Comment: Thats because Class1 `$obs` has no implementation yet. so no value assigned in `$obs`

Comment: It is assigned a value in Class1Service, which is provided as Class1 on injection. I would assume that i get an exception when subscribing to it, since it would be null or undefined.

Comment: Hello Simon, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r1vmgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here is working demo, Class1 injecting giving Class1Service so You need to inject class1 every class, then it will works fine.

Comment: Hello, Simon. If you use `useExisting` instead of `useClass` than evetything working fine at your side. Reason for this is that `useExisting` giving you same instance of `Class1Service` to both component, while `useClass` giving you different instance of `class1Service` so, thats why in your case when you have used useClass giving you another class1Instance, thats why class1 will not be the same instance of class1Service, and nothing data gona be dispayed. if You change useClass to useExisting then it will be fine..

Comment: I think it's because your `Class1` is not `providedIn: 'root'`

Comment: @eko that will not work. Because Class1 is used with useClass of class1Service, and class1Service has already provided in root, so two different instance is created for Class1service.. To avoid this he needs to replace useClass with useExisting.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I read something completely different, thanks. Don't mind my comment :-)

Comment: @eko you can get example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r1vmgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclass1.ts